# Having issue using max_width using inyMCE 5

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I have been trying to set the maximum width so that the editor is not so big but it does not seem to work.
I am using TINYMCE 5 direct from tinymce CDN

I am using max_width: 500,but it does not seem to limit it to 500px, I tried changing it to 500px but still does not work. The example in the online documentation dont use px

tinymce.init({

    selector: 'textarea.mceEditor',
    max_width: 500,
    
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    
    resize: 'both',

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing running code it is hard to say for sure what the issue is but the `max_width` setting combined with an initial width and the ability to resize horizontally does indeed stop resizing at 500px.

If I use this configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table paste"
],
max_width: 500,
width: 300,
height: 400,
resize: 'both',
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
```

});

...the editor starts 300px wide and I can expand it to (but not past) 500px.

By default TinyMCE will take up the full width of its containing element so if your containing element is wider than 500px the editor will start wider than your desired max value.  If you try to resize it after initialization it will enforce the `max_width` value.

Here is a working example:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/ABhaab/1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
max_width is how wide the editor can be resized by a user, not the maximum width the editor will take up.